# Why do actions on index.php run when Wordpress loads other pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, templates, action

I have "Front page displays" set to "Your latest posts" in the `Settings > Reading` section of the Wordpress dashboard and I want to use `front-page.php` as my landing page.

I don't really have any use for `index.php` outside of it being a fallback. I guess as a fallback, I'd just want to display the home page, so I just included `front-page.php` in `index.php`:

**index.php**

`<?php include('front-page.php'); ?>`

The problem is that inside of `front-page.php`, I have some actions running.

**front-page.php**

`<?php do_action('myaction'); ?>`

When I load the site, `front-page.php`, these actions all seem to be running twice. Why are actions on `index.php` running when `front-page.php` is being loaded?

This lead me to remove the `include()` statement inside `index.php` and just use an empty `index.php` file. That can't be right though? Why are these actions running twice when the page loads?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress uses a `.htaccess` file to redirect all request to `index.php`, which then loads the wanted page.
In your case, this means going to `/front-page.php` first loads `index.php` which then loads `front-page.php`.

In order to redirect to `front-page.php`, I would suggest you to do the following steps in index.php:

- Look if the current url is `index.php`
- If we're on the index, send a redirect header `Header("Location: front-page.php");` followed by `exit` or `die`.
- If not, keep loading as usual

Comment: Ok, that makes sense then. How would you detect the URL? I tried using `error_log(get_page_template())` and apparently it was looking for `page.php` when I loaded `front-page.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always place some "test" text in the file you suspect may be loading to make sure you're seeing the correct file.  Just put

TEST

or something in the file and see if it shows on screen. Now you know which file is loading.

It will default to index.php many times if you're intended file isn't coded right or if it's named improperly. I have had this issue before!